# Eloquent doesn't call table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to filter results by name of a relationship

```
$questions = Question::whereHas('category', function ($q) use ($coh) {
   $q->where('id', $coh->id);
})->get();
```

And i'm gettign the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
>   'questions.question_category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `question_categories` where `questions`.`question_category_id` =
>   `question_categories`.`id` and `question_categories`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Reading the error is obvious why it isn't working, is because eloquent or me are not calling the question table, shouldn't it called it automatically because i'm putting Question::??

Comment: Show you `Question` model and `Category` model, It would be good you can include migrations of your tables too

Comment: If I understand your code, you want to have all question in a specific category. So isn't better to do `$category->questions` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your **Question** model and the following line in your **category()**

```
class Question extends Model{
   public function category(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'category_id');
   }
}
```

Then try to hit the query

```
$questions = Question::whereHas('category', function ($q) use ($coh) {
    $q->where('id', $coh->id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the relationship should be that a **Question belongsTo category** and a **Category hasMany questions**.

So in order to filter you could do it different ways depending on the attributes of your table.
If you want to do it with Questions, since you have the category_id as a Foreing Key you could do something like this(***assuming your foreing key field is named = 'question_category_id'***):

```
$questions = Question::("question_category_id", "=", $coh);
```

As someone mentioned you could also use the Category Model to access all questions **belonging** to that Category since you should have defined in your Category Model that each category **hasMany** Questions.